# JPA mapping primary key in one table with 2 foreign keys in another table

Tags: jpa

I have a primary key in  one table and which is  linked to 2 foreign keys in other table.
how to do mapping in this scenario and how to decide fetching type and cascading type.
I am new to JPA so any inputs will be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Refer link below this would help and give you samples of one to many relation as in your case:-
http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/OneToMany